# I got to go to the party

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense

I need to know the literal meaning of this "*I got to go to the party*."

Did someone actually go to the party (as in I went to the party) or he had the opportunity of going to the party regardless of the fact whether he went to the party or not?

Comment: The (rather "slangy") construction [***to get**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get-to-do-something#:~:text=From%20Longman%20Dictionary%20of%20Contemporary,the%20place%20with%20her%20job.) [to do something]* is invariably defined as ***to have the opportunity to do something / chance of doing it***. But it always implies *taking up that opportunity* (i.e. - ***actually** doing it*).

Comment: ...in respect of ***future*** actions, note that if a 17-year-old Brit says *I **get to** vote after my next birthday*, that very strongly implies he ***intends*** to vote when he's eligible. If instead he'd said *I **will be able** to vote...* that strong implication of ***intending*** to vote wouldn't be there (so the ***be able to*** version could reasonably be followed by ***...but I doubt if I actually will vote***, but that would be "unusual / acceptable" after the ***get to*** version).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So if i say i get to vote that will have strong intention as in i will for sure vote and if i say i got to vote then i  could interpret its meaning that i actually voted. Am i correct

Comment: @FumbleFingers so is " I get to" version is equivalent to "certain will"as in future? I want to know the literal meaning of "i get to vote".

Comment: @FumbleFingers is it "I get to vote" said in present tense or future tense(as in i vote or i will vote)

Comment: *I [**will**] **get** to vote after his next birthday*. It doesn't normally make any difference whether you include that "explicit" future ***will*** or not. But if you wanted to emphasise that you were *determined* to  become "enfranchised" as soon as legally possible (by making *sure* your name was correctly entered on the electoral roll, perhaps), you'd need to include the word ***will*** so you could enunciate it with heavy stress to convey the strength of your commitment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know sometimes we use present tense to refer to future and as you said "I [will] get to vote after next birthday" does not make any difference but if I exclude "after his birthday" and just say "I get to vote" then i reckon it is expressing present tense and its meaning must be different from "I will get to vote" which is for future.

Comment: I suspect you reckon wrong. It's incredibly difficult to come up with a real-world context where ***I get to vote*** could refer to one's ***current*** status [of being enfranchised] without simultaneously referring to having and exercising that ability in the ***future***. Obviously there are some contexts where what you ***do*** and what you ***will do*** can carry significantly different meanings, but "getting to vote" isn't likely to be one of them.

Comment: A native speaker would more likely say ***I can vote*** or similar in some unusual context where he didn't particularly want to imply reference to any *specific* future vote-casting, simply to the fact of his current eligibility to vote. That's because ***I get to vote*** carries such strong implications of *actually* voting (in the ***future***). This quite naturally follows from the metaphoric imagery of ***get to** [do something]*, because you "get to" ***the future*** (or the future "arrives"). Time is thus equated with "distance to be travelled".

Comment: @FumbleFingwrs Thank you but apart from this "vote example". Would  "get to do something" signal present or future.Eg "I get to sing a song" "I get to write a novel" "I get to play cricket"

Comment: @Fumble Fingers do these examples mean whether i do these things or i will do these things?

Comment: I'm going to turn it round, and suggest that _get to_ isn't about opportunity, but about expectation: _get to do something_ means "to do that thing where either you couldn't before, or you weren't expecting to be able to".

Comment: @Colin Fine so "get to do something" is not about usual thing which we do daily (simple present) as in if i say "I get to sing a song daily. Would that be wrong? And what i understood is "I get to sing a song" means, I am about to sing. (As in wait a moment I sing)

Comment: LIke most "simple present" forms, _I get to_ is not usually used for right now. It is either general/habitual, or future. In _If I get to the party in time tomorrow I get to sing a song_ it's future. It could equally be _I'll get to sing a song_: English has many ways of expressing future time, and most of them do not involve the modal expression that traditionalists insist on calling the "future tense". In _When I manage to get home in time to go to the bar on a Saturday night, I get to sing a song_ it's timeless.

Comment: @Colin Fine Thank you  i believe i am almost clear.How about "why do not you sleep Sarah ". "Ok Mom i get to sleep" here "I get to"is used for "right now" probably because "get to sleep is fixed expression?

Comment: No, @BilalZafar, _get to sleep_ is usually understood in the other sense I mentioned in the other thread, _gradually enter a state_ (like "get to know", "get to understand"), and not in the "achievement" sense we are mainly talking about here. But in whatever meaning, _I get to sleep_ **cannot** refer to right now. It is usually  habitual (_I find if I meditate before I go to bed then I get to sleep easily_).

Comment: Thank you Colin Fine :) I completely understood it now.

Comment: @BilalZafar: Compare 1) *I get to sleep easily when I avoid coffee* and 2) *I get to sleep with my girlfriend when her parents are away*. Where in #1 ***get to sleep*** just means ***fall asleep***, but in #2 it's ***get to** [do something]* - meaning ***have the chance** [to do it]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't suppose you'd want to cobble an answer together from your several hundred words of "comment"? ;)

Answer (score 3):

The "literal" meaning of the rather "slangy" construction ***to get** [to do something]* is ***to have the opportunity** [to do it]* - always with the implication of taking up that opportunity (*actually* doing it).

In respect of future actions, if a 17-year-old Brit says *I get to vote after my next birthday*, that very strongly implies he *intends* to vote when he becomes eligible. If instead he'd said *I will be able to vote...* that strong implication of intending to vote wouldn't be there. So the *be able to...* version could reasonably be followed by *...but I doubt if I actually will vote*, but that would be "unusual / acceptable" after the *get to...* version.

Note that *[to] **get** [to]* often just functions as an "auxiliary" verb in English, with little or no semantic content, so it's actually *optional* in the following example - which means the same regardless of whether ***get to*** is present or not...

> 1: *I [**get to**] sleep easily when I avoid coffee*

But with the "have the opportunity" idiomatic usage being asked about here, it makes a significant difference whether ***get to*** is present or not...

> 2: *I [**get to**] sleep with my girlfriend when her parents are away*

In #2 above, including ***get to*** forces the implication *I **am able to...** [do something that I **want** to do]*. If those two words *aren't* present, it's simply a neutral statement about what happens in that situation.

*Finally*, note that with OP's exact example, ***got*** is definitely a Past Tense usage *(I **was** able to go to the party)*. But there's also the "Present" Tense / Infinitive usage *to **have** [got] to do something*, meaning *to be **obliged** to do it*. With *that* usage, auxiliary ***have*** is often omitted in casual speech, and ***go to*** is often transcribibed as a single word...

> 3: *I **gotta** go to the party*
> (I ***must*** go to the party - but with the strong implication that I don't actually ***want*** to go)

Comment: Indeed; if you said "I got to go to the party" and your friend asked how it was and you replied that you didn't go, your friend would be very perplexed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as Colin Fine said earlier that "I get to sleep/get to know/get to understand are states where we are entering into instead of "I am able to" and according to you 'I get to sleep" could be both. Then how about " I get to know/understand". Could these two also be as in "I am able to"? If yes then could "I get to sleep/know/understand" be as in "Will be able to" as well?

Comment: *I'm a teacher. Our school has a "Parents' Evening" at the start of each term, so I **get to know** the parents as well as the pupils* - where the highlighted element is syntactically and semantically ambiguous. Only the speaker himself can be sure if there's any allusion to *having the **opportunity** / being **able** to* meet the parents with *...get to **know*** in that *exact* context. But if we change it to *...get to **meet***, there's no doubt at all that's what's meant (if it *wasn't*, the speaker would simply drop the words ***get to***, but he can't do that with *get to **know***).